# What should I add in the Update to apply the lookAtSpecificTarget flag and the lookAtSpecificTargetIndex changes at run time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FLookAnimator lookAnimator;
    public Transform[] targets;
    public bool lookAtSpecificTarget = false;
    public int lookAtSpecificTargetIndex;
    public float switchingTime;
    public bool switchingLoop = false;

    private bool loopOnce = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        if (lookAtSpecificTarget && targets.Length > 0)
        {
            if (lookAtSpecificTargetIndex >= 0)
            {
                lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[lookAtSpecificTargetIndex];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(SwitchTargetsPeriodically());
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator SwitchTargetsPeriodically()
    {
        for (int i = 0; true; i = (i + 1) % targets.Length)
        {
            if (i <= targets.Length - 1 && switchingLoop)
            {
                loopOnce = true;

                lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
            }

            if (switchingLoop == false && loopOnce)
            {
                if (i <= targets.Length - 1)
                {
                    lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
                }

                if (i == (targets.Length - 1))
                {
                    loopOnce = false;
                }
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(switchingTime);
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine the first time when running the game but what should I do in the Update to apply the changes of the flag and index of the target in the Update at run time?

The goal is to be able to switch the target index for looking at run time if the flag is true.
if the flag is false don't use the lookAtSpecificTargetIndex and continue with the Coroutine but if the flag set to true then pause the Coroutine and use the lookAtSpecificTargetIndex :

```
lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[lookAtSpecificTargetIndex];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a quick way just for the editor you can use [`[ContextMenu]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html) like

```
private Coroutine _routine;

[ContextMenu(nameof(ApplyTargetIndex))]
private void ApplyLookAtTarget()
{
    if (lookAtSpecificTarget && targets.Length > 0)
    {
        if(_routine!= null) StopCoroutine(_routine);
        _routine = null;

        if (lookAtSpecificTargetIndex >= 0)
        {
            lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[lookAtSpecificTargetIndex];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _routine = StartCoroutine(SwitchTargetsPeriodically());
    }
}
```

this allows you to execute this method via the Context menu of the Inspector of your component